# Power BI DateDiff seems to return incorrect number of days

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff

I'm using DAX `DateDiff` in Power BI to calculate the number of days between two dates, like this:

```
DaysDiff = DATEDIFF('MyTable'[Sales Order Date],
                    'MyTable'[Paid Date],DAY)
```

The formula is however returning some odd looking results, such as:

[image]

I would expect to see the actual number of days between the dates. For example, the number of days between 3/31/2017 and 12/4/2017 should be *248*.

Both source columns are formatted as dates, and appear in the actual data as shown here.

How should the difference be calculated? I also tried a different formulation, which returns the same result:

```
DayDiff = 1.* ('MyTable'[Paid Date]-'MyTable'[Sales Order Date])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the hint of the `DaysDiff`, my guess is that you have multiple records with same `Sales Order Date` and `Paid Date`, and Power BI has aggregated (default `Sum`) the results of all to one number.

If you change the summarization to either `Average`/`Minimum`/`Maximum` it should work fine.

[image: result]

Comment: That was it - was summarizing when it should not. Thanks!